# Unique together in Django User Model

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to update Django User table, and add another field into it. This is how I do.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Now, since there's a field `USERNAME_FIELD` which takes a unique field. However, I want that `username and platform` should be `unique_together`, not just `username`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: I'm aware of this meta field. However, I doubt this will work because inheriting the `AbstractUser` model requires a `USERNAME_FIELD` which should be unique. And  Django User model also work on a principle that one field inside the `User` model should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

AbstractUser is a mostly-complete model that defines a set of default fields, including username uniqueness. If that doesn't work for you, then you should inherit from AbstractBaseUser instead and define the full set of fields.

Comment: Even `AbstractBaseUser` takes a unique field `USERNAME_FIELD`. I rather want to have 2 fields as `unique_together`.

Comment: Any lead to it?

Comment: No it doesn't. It doesn't define a username field at all, and doesn't impose any constraints.

Comment: `AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'`

Comment: This is the error that I get. Basically, it internally checks `if cls.USERNAME_FIELD in cls.REQUIRED_FIELDS`, hence an error.

Comment: No, the error is because you have not declared USERNAME_FIELD on that class (it's a startup check). But this has nothing to do with uniqueness, you just need to set that attribute to point to your username field.

Comment: No. If USERNAME_FIELD is set, then that field should be unique. This is the error that I get. `login.User: (auth.E003) 'User.email' must be unique because it is named as the 'USERNAME_FIELD'.`

Comment: Need something similar... what did you end up doing? Maybe there is a solution with a `@property` field that returns a concatenated string of platform and email?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i have the same issue, but according to your answer and comments, it  doesn't worked at all, in fact it doesn't make any difference by using either AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser to solve this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness on the username field is only if you use the built-in authentication backend.

Directly from the django docs

> If you use the default authentication backend, then your model must have a single unique field...A non-unique username field is allowed if you use a custom authentication backend that can support it.

[Django Custom Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From your question and the comments its pretty clear(if i am not fully misunderstood) that you want to save an user with an `email` (an identifier) with multiple `platform`. If this is the case, you can use a `postgres ArrayField`  on your `platform` column if your database is Postgresql, or alternavely you can use `JsonField` provided by django.

1. [Postgresql Array Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) available in django > 1.7
2. [Django Json Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield)

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late to answer this but the solution I used recently for the same problem is:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    platform_and_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'platform_and_email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "App User"
        verbose_name_plural = "App Users"
```

You can use a single field and set it as unique. On the client side of your app you can authenticate user by doing 'platform_' + email behind the scenes.

You will also have to write your own custom backend and make it use your **platform_and_email** field to validate and authenticate.

Let me know if you need more explanation on this.